# Not able to get the imputed data frame after cannot coerce class ""missForest"" to a data.frame

Tags: analytics, missing-data

I am not able to get the imputed data frame after running the missForest package.

I am taking the sample data to check missForest.

```
iris.na <- iris
set.seed(111)
for (i in 1:4) iris.na[sample(150, sample(20)), i] <- NA
iris.imp<-missForest(iris.na)
```

After running the above code , I am not able to use the `iris.imp` as a data set and also not able to import externaly. I am getting the below error:

> cannot coerce class ""missForest"" to a data.frame

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `iris.imp$ximp`, which is already a dataframe:

```
class(iris.imp$ximp)
iris_imp_df <- iris.imp$ximp
```